# Scaling website to 100% width/height of visible area

Tags: iphone, android, mobile-website

how to make content of a web page fully scaled whatever the width/height of the device visible portion is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no" />
```

works as a meta tag as well, if you want to let users scale the site just do not use minimumscale, maximumscale and user-scalable attributes.

Answer (score 1):

In iphone

```
webview.scalesPageToFit = YES;
```

All the best.